# Sum over the principal minors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a skew-symmetric $n \times n$ matrix and write $$\det\left(\lambda I - \frac{1}{2\pi}A\right) = \sum_{k=0}^n g_k(A)\lambda^{n-k}.$$ Then is $g_{2k}(A)$ is expressible as $$g_{2k}(A)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{2k}(2k)!}\sum \delta_{i_1,\dots,i_{2k}}^{j_1,\dots,j_{2k}}a^{i_1}_{j_1}\cdots a^{i_{2k}}_{j_{2k}}$$

and how is this sum related to summing over the principal $2k \times 2k$ minors of $A$ since these are exactly what $g_k(A)$'s are supposed to be?

Also I'm not sure if the $(2k)!$ term should be in the denominator or, if the skew-symmetry is relevant.

This looks quite a bit like the algebraic definition for the determinant i.e.

$$
\det(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)a^1_{\sigma(1)}\cdots a^n_{\sigma(n)}.
$$

Comment: I thought I addressed this in the comments on your first question. A similar expansion holds for every $k$, not just even ones, and for every $n\times n$ matrix. But for a skew-symmetric matrix, the odd ones vanish. The factorial factor is there because each $2k$-tuple of distinct numbers $i_1,i_2,\dots,i_{2k}$ appears $(2k)!$ times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, we have
$$p_A(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I - A) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \sigma_k(A)\lambda^{n-k}.$$
It is worth remarking that $\sigma_k(A)$ is the $k$th symmetric function of the eigenvalues of $A$, as you can check by noting that the left-hand side is invariant under replacing $A$ with $PAP^{-1}$ and putting $A$ in upper-triangular form.

Use the usual complete expansion of the determinant
$$\det(B) = \sum_{\pi\in S_n} \text{sgn}(\pi) b_1^{\pi(1)}\cdots b_n^{\pi(n)} = \sum \delta_{1\cdots n}^{i_1\cdots i_n}b_1^{i_1}\cdots b_n^{i_n} = \frac1{n!}\sum \delta_{j_1\cdots j_n}^{i_1\cdots i_n}b_{j_1}^{i_1}\cdots b_{j_n}^{i_n}.$$
Now, for $B=\lambda I - A$, we realize that to get a $\lambda^{n-k}$ term, we must have permutations $\pi$ with $\pi(j)=j$ for $n-k$ different $j$, and so this requires that such a $\pi$ permute the remaining $k$ values of $j$.
Let $I$ denote the multiindex $i_1\cdots i_k$ with $i_1<i_2<\dots<i_k$, and let $I'$ be the (increasingly ordered) complementary multiindex. Let $J$ be any reordering of $I$ and let $J'=I'$. Then $\delta_{J,J'}^{I,I'} = \delta_J^I$.

The coefficient, then, of $\lambda^{n-k}$ will be
$$(-1)^k\sum_I \delta_{j_1,\dots,j_k}^{i_1,\dots,i_k} a_{i_1}^{j_1}\cdots a_{i_k}^{j_k} = (-1)^k\frac1{k!}\sum\delta_{j_1,\dots,j_k}^{i_1,\dots,i_k} a_{i_1}^{j_1}\cdots a_{i_k}^{j_k}.$$
Note that (without the sign) this is precisely the sum of the $k\times k$ principal minors (for $I$ fixed, we are calculating the determinant of the matrix with rows and columns $I$).

Note that $p_{A^\top}(\lambda) = p_A(\lambda)$ and so when $A$ is skew-symmetric we have $p_A(\lambda)=p_{-A}(\lambda)$. Since $\sigma_k(-A)=(-1)^k\sigma_k(A)$, we conclude that when $A$ is skew-symmetric $\sigma_k(A)=0$ for $k$ odd.

Comment: Thank you. This addresses my question. Just for clarification, are we talking about leading principal minors or just any principal minors here? @ted-shifrin

Comment: Of course *all* principal minors. Remember that you want something that is meaningful for a linear map (invariant under change of basis). A leading principal minor certainly won't be that, and you'll only have one of them, right?

Comment: Got it. My combinatorics is a bit rusty so I had to take a while to undedrstand why $(-1)^k\frac1{k!}\sum\delta_{j_1,\dots,j_k}^{i_1,\dots,i_k} a_{i_1}^{j_1}\cdots a_{i_k}^{j_k}$ results in the sum of $k\times k$ principal minors. I think the only place I had seen something related to this before was with $\text{tr}(\text{adj}(A))$, which gives the sum of the cofactors $C_{ii}$ and since $(-1)^{i+i}=1$ we get the sum of the $n-1 \times n-1$ principal minors, but I couldn't make this work for other than the $n-1 \times n-1$ case. @ted-shifrin

Comment: As I commented to you on the earlier post, (ignoring constants) for fixed $i_1,\dots,i_k$ this is just the determinant of the $k\times k$ matrix you get by using rows *and columns* $i_1,\dots,i_k$. This seems to be the thing you need to come to terms with. For any other choice of columns, the $\delta$ gives you a zero coefficient.